# What's the alternative of before_filter from Rails in Phoenix/Elixir?

Tags: rest, elixir, phoenix-framework

In my Phoenix application, I have a pipe and scope "api"

```
  pipeline :api do
    plug(:accepts, ["json"])
  end


  scope "/api" .....
    # .....
  end
```

How can I protect it by an API Key which is passed through a special header? That is, I'd like something like this:

```
defmodule MyApp.MyController do
  use MyApp.Web, :controller

  :before_filter :authenticate_user_by_api_key!


  def authenticate_user_by_api_key!(conn, params) do
    # check if a header exists and key is valid
  end
end
```

I'm planning on validating a header. **How can I do that without relying on any third-party libraries?**

Also. If I wanted to use a **module** instead of a single function, how would I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails' before\_filter equivalent in Phoenix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958446/rails-before-filter-equivalent-in-phoenix)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Local Plug

If it's a local method, you can simply use the `plug` construct within the controller.

```
defmodule MyApp.MyController do
  use MyApp.Web, :controller

  plug :authenticate_user_by_api_key!


  defp authenticate_user_by_api_key!(conn, params) do
    # Authenticate or something
  end
end
```

*[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958446/rails-before-filter-equivalent-in-phoenix) and read more about [Plugs here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug).*

---

### Module Plug

If you'd like to call the function from a Module, your module must export the `init/1` and `call/2` methods:

```
defmodule MyApp.Plugs.Authentication do
  import Plug.Conn

  def init(default), do: default

  def call(conn, default) do
    # Check header for API Key
  end
end
```

And use it like this in your controller:

```
defmodule MyApp.MyController do
  use MyApp.Web, :controller

  plug MyApp.Plugs.Authentication

  # Controller Methods
end
```

*Read the [Phoenix Guide on Module Plugs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/plug.html#module-plugs) for more details.*

Comment: thanks. If I wanted to use a module instead of a single function, how would I   do that?

Comment: @Meji Updated the answer

Comment: that's not an answer. what should MyApp.Plugs.Authentication
 look like? What functions does it have to have? what function will be called?

Comment: or maybe it's me who hadn't noticied