# Simplify Phoenix controller actions

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In my Phoenix application I have the following actions in controller:

```
  def edit(conn, %{"id" => topic_id}) do
    topic = Repo.get(Topic, topic_id)
    changeset = Topic.changeset(topic)

    render conn, :edit, changeset: changeset, topic: topic
  end

  def update(conn, %{"id" => topic_id, "topic" => topic_params}) do
    topic = Repo.get(Topic, topic_id)
    changeset = Topic.changeset(topic, topic_params)

    case Repo.update(changeset) do
      {:ok, _topic} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Topic Updated")
        |> redirect(to: topic_path(conn, :index))

      {:error, changeset} ->
        render conn, :edit, changeset: changeset, topic: topic
    end
  end
```

This line is duplicated in those functions:

```
topic = Repo.get(Topic, topic_id)
```

Is there any way to refactor it? 
In Ruby on Rails I will use the before action, how can I do it in Phoenix?

I've tried something like this:

```
  plug :set_topic when action in [:edit, :update]

  def set_topic(conn, %{"id" => topic_id}) do
    topic =  Repo.get!(Topic, topic_id)

    assign(conn, :topic, topic)
  end
```

It returns `no function clause matching in Discuss.TopicController.set_topic/2`. That's because `set_topic` does not have access to request params. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958446/rails-before-filter-equivalent-in-phoenix but it won't really be shorter if you just have one duplicated line.

Comment: @Dogbert Thanks for reply. I still cannot make it work. I updated my post.

Comment: I believe the functions that are called by a plug accept different params, check out the docs

Comment: @MateuszUrbański Try `Repo.get!(Topic, conn.params["id"])` and ignore the second argument of the function. Like @JustMichael said, plugs don't get params as the second argument (that answer is most likely incorrect).

Comment: Or with pattern matching `def set_topic(conn = %{params: %{"id" => topic_id}}, _)`.

Comment: First of all - your plug can't work, because the second argument is not provided in `plug :set_topic when action in [:edit, :update]`. Second thing - I'm really agree with @Dogbert in his first comment - you create new function for just one duplicated line.